# SWT: how to start a new line in a label?

Tags: java, swt, label

I want to make a label that will contain a few strings, each one in a new line.
For example: how to make `label.setText(srt1/nstr2);` look like this :

> string1
>
> string2

I've tried to use `/n` but it doesn't work. so, what should I do it?

Comment: Use \n rather than /n

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me. See if this helps.

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class MultiLineLabel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);

        Label l = new Label(shell, SWT.WRAP);
        l.setText("First Line\nSecond Line");

        l.pack();
        shell.pack();
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

[image]